# Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts helper method throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, nullreferenceexception

I keep getting this error when trying to navigate to my LogOn page:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The line of code that is throwing the error on is:

```
<%= Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this, options, null)%>.
```

Does anyone know why this line of code would be throwing an error?

Comment: Have you found this link: http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/5f4c9e4e68608676/dac714e031d6a14e?#dac714e031d6a14e ? `I suspect though that you're missing the "OpenIdDiscover" named route in your global.asax.cs file.`

Comment: Is this mis-tagged? The Html object, and the .OpenIdSelectorScripts extension method are for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: It didn't have either tag.  I added asp.net because technically it's a catch-all (ASP.NET MVC vs. ASP.NET WebForms)   But you're right, probably MVC.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the answer! All I need to do was add the route in the global.asax.cs file. Now this is my first time posting a question, so how do I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Tim: Can you convert this comment into an answer so we can upvote it and get this question off the "Unanswered" list?  Thanks.  :)

Comment: @Bill: Glad i could help, added as question :)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this link: [Gougle-Groups/DotNetOpenAuth](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/5f4c9e4e68608676/dac714e031d6a14e?pli=1): 
*"I suspect though that you're missing the `OpenIdDiscover` named route in your `global.asax.cs` file."*