# CS1501: No overload for method > 'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 2 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dotnetopenauth

I'm getting this error using openId in MVC3.

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method
>   'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 2 arguments
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 63:             </p>
Line 64:        </div>
Line 65:     @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(options, null))
```

This web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"
             publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Help please

Comment: may be it uses 3 arguments? [Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts helper method][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138534/html-openidselectorscripts-helper-method-throwing-nullreferenceexception

Comment: It was initially throwing an error OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 3 arguments
this was the code before
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this.Page,options, null))
I read a post saying to remove this.page to solve the problem.But I got this error now